# switch OpAmp down to minimize power consumption

Tags: batteries, operational-amplifier, pmos, power-consumption

I'm currently designing a board which senses some stuff. The board is powered using a 6V lithium battery. According to my sensor+OpAmp logic I need to split the voltage into +/-3V.
The circuitry to split that voltage consume 0.6mA and the remaining OpAmp+sensor consumes 1.2mA.

I wish to minimize that by powering this circuitry only when I want to make my measurement, and then switch the all things off, until the next measurement.

I though about using a P-mos directly between the battery positiv pin and the voltage splitter input. According to my simulation, that could work, but I'm wondering if you guys have some inputs or advices to help me ;)

- OpAmp with shutdown mode?!
- ...?
- ...?

Comment: I assume you have a uC on board. If it runs at 5V you might be able to power you analog stuff directly from a GPIO pin.

Comment: @wouter Yes! Almost zero parts. 1.8 mA is easy. Remember an RC filter for bus noise. And don't violate maximum pin current, even for a microsecond charging that C.

Answer (score 1):

Opamps with shutdown pins do exist, but they tend to be on more specialised ones, since the standard dual and quad opamp pinouts don't have room for shutdown pins. It'd be worth looking to see if there are any that satisfy your requirements, however, as there are some very good low power opamps out there that will also draw less current when active than your current solution.

Using a P MOSFET between the battery and the rail splitter is also a valid option. Bear in mind that P MOSFETs have higher on resistance than their more common N MOSFET cousins, though given the power draw you're likely dealing with that's probably not a problem. Make sure the FET you select has a suitable gate voltage; if your MCU is running with the split rail as gnd, you've only got 3 volts to work with.

Comment: Thank you Nick for you answer ! It was stupid to use a 6V battery, when I could use 2 3V batteries in serie and have +/-3V from that. So I can now save some power from the splitter. so now, I'm using one N-mos and P-mos for -3 and 3v respectivly. I'm driving the P-mos directly from the uC. The N-mos is drived by another PNP (2n3906) which swings the voltage between +/-3V on its gate. I wish I can send you the schematics so that you can criticize it.

Comment: That all sounds pretty sensible to me!

Answer (score 0):

here is the power supply side of my circuit. Please fill free to criticize it ;)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkNyZu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In fact, I'm not using a square voltage (V8) instead I'm switching the power supply on, only during 5ms at 2hz.

Comment: for anyone reading this : "It works like a charm"